# Unable to add printer to application using PrintService in Android

Tags: java, android, printing

img_link : https://imgur.com/a/v53gyfk

I configure an application that supports PrintService, but it says Unable to add a printer to the application output with a picture. What values ​​do I need to modify to make it appear as Add Printer?

I can print normally using PrintService and referencing developer.android.com didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you please add some code which you tried?

Comment: I implemented the common code to implement the printservice and printdiscovery code and register them in the manifest. I couldn't attach it because I don't know what code is controlling the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it If you add `android:permission="android.permission.START_PRINT_SERVICE_CONFIG_ACTIVITY"` and set the exported property as `true` to the activity registered as addPrintersActivity in the printservice-related xml file in AndroidManifest's service, you can add printing from Android's default print service normally.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).